# Hibernate:HQL for a notification system

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping, named-query

i am working on project using hibernate and Spring , i have a came to a phase where i ahve to deal with  a notification system based on this class diagram .

[image: class Diagram]

the logic behind this class diagram is :

1. Every notification has a type
2. a user chose the type of notifications that he wants to be notify on , the i save  the ID of **user** and Id of **notification** in **userType**
3. if a user see a notification , i add his ID and the Id this notification in  **seenNotifications**

what i want to do is to write  named queries using HQL to select :

1. all notifications of a user that he choosed to be **notify** on **and** he didnt see them yet .
2. all notification of a user that he choosed to be **notify** on **and** he already saw .

Can you help me with this please? and thank you